# How to send JavaScript errors to sentry?

Tags: javascript, sentry

I'm trying to send all JavaScript's errors to Sentry.

I read Sentry's Installation docs（https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/install/） and chose `So for example:`

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.17.0/raven.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>Raven.config('https://[code]@sentry.io/[code]').install();</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I checked that raven.js was loaded and overwrided `window.onerror`.

[image: error log in Google Chrome Console]
[image: raven js code]

I could send notifications if I use `Manually Reporting Errors` like this.

```
try {
  doSomething(a[0])
} catch(e) {
  Raven.captureException(e)
}
```

But I couldn't capture any uncaught exception if I don't use `Manually Reporting Errors`.

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give Sentry a context within which to work. Otherwise it wont know where to look.

Take a look at the top of the docs here:
https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/usage/

So wrap the code in a sentry context and you should be good to go.